# Motherboard recommendations

Tags: motherboard

I have an old pc with a 3rd generation i7 3370, 1155 socket. My problem is that my motherboard seems to be in the end of its life, and I want to change it before it's too late. I'm not planning on upgrading my cpu, so if you guys can recommend me a good motherboard that is also good for gaming, becuase I have an 750gtx ti on this machine, it will be appreciated. By the way, I don't have a budget but I don't want to spend more than 150$ on this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Honestly, for an older 1155 MOBO, I would suggest shopping used first, since you will usually find much better deals than shopping for new older socket MOBOs.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any website apart from amazon or ebay that you would recommend that ships outside the US?

Comment: @JeffryRomero You could also try Newegg (newegg.com). They ship internationally.